# Need help in Webscraping T20 World Cup 2022 data

Tags: python, pandas, csv, web-scraping, parsing

I have a list of links of **match scorecards** and i have stored the  respective html content of each link in a list. I **need to get the csv files I am attaching as the output.**  Any help would be appreciated. Check the screenshots and the csv files. Also here is the link of the website which I am scraping the data from: https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?id=14450;type=tournament
I am using **python** as my programming language.

**Drive link of the screenshots:** https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PcTPBvrhHBLhJGlP2NBo35PA9Z4IagLC?usp=sharing

**Drive link of the csv files:**   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1kpsSbN8M1W1aD-slVAL1YWmnYHesEMKC?usp=sharing